# isDirty issue with react hook form and react number format

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-number-format

I'm using `react-number-format` with `react-hook-form` `Controller` for a currency input.

**The `formState` does not update correctly:** `isDirty` and `dirtyFields` do not seem to update when editing the masked number input and then deleting the text.

I set the `defaultValues` to `''` (empty string).

If I input a number, I can see that `isDirty` is true. But if I delete the input, and the value is `''` (empty string) I still see `isDirty` is true - but the value is exactly the same as the defaultValue.

[image: Edit react hook form with react number format isDirty issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with line 54 in the file `masked-hook-form-inputs.js`:

`onChange(values.floatValue);` the value of `floatValue` can be `undefined`, and this caused the problem.

**The solutionn**
Change line 54 to `onChange(isNaN(values.floatValue) ? '' : values.floatValue);`

Note that it's better to use `''` (empty string) and not `null`.